# Angular ng-init assignment inside of a template

Tags: angularjs

I need to initialize an object in my view and assign a reference to it.

Can I achieve this by using ng-init? Is it an assignment by value or reference?

```
<ANY ng-init="objA = objB"> ... </ANY>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move assignment to controller `init()` method.

`ng-init` is directive that have a very lot of side effects and hardly to trace it down. For example: when you use `ng-init` in directive template for creating/editing item and you assign some `model` value in it - you will achieve problem with editing that actually should use already existing value.

As well side effect of it is executing few times when you add `ng-if`.

Usage `ng-init` in templates are your own risk.

Right way: `controller` data should be defined at start of module - in any case any view started in order: `$state` -> `resolve()` -> `controller` -> `template` -> `directive`. It's not a good idea to fool yourself with not existing data until it will be created by magic.

In case of repeaters when you have for example empty `{}` and you need to display it like possibility to fill yet empty input, as I mentioned - you need to run function on init that can define empty or extend existing model by passing actual model.

Comment: thanks! anyways it would good to know if ng-init assigns by value or reference

Comment: you need speed - use value. you aware of side-effects - use reference function. In some of my cases when I've used function passed with `model` (`ng-init="ctrl.initValue(item)" ng-model="item"`) that was actually a link, and I was free to update it depending on `edit` state or fill with default value if it's in `new` state. In case of `ng-repeat` it's better to pass `$index` to avare of not creating link Object.

Comment: Anyway ngInit is one time function until you add ngIf